# Why won't my fieldtype plugin save the settings form values?

Tags: plugins

I have a custom field. The FieldType plugin provides a settings form that adds a field to the form. The field is a group of checkboxes...think the paragraph types selection when adding a entity revisions field to a content type.

The form displays correctly. Two of the checkboxes are checked by default correctly. But the values don't get saved.

I've put a breakpoint where the settings are retrieved:

```
   $def = $items->getFieldDefinition();
   return $def->getSetting('allowed_schemes') ?? UrlItem::getSchemes();
```

which returns null, as does $def->getSettings(). I've also put a breakpoint in FieldItemBase where it retrieves the settings...also null.

It might have something to do with the schema method. I haven't figured out yet what I need to put there.

Here is my plugin.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\url_text\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Defines the 'url' entity field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "url",
 *   label = @Translation("URL"),
 *   description = @Translation("A field containing a plain string URL value."),
 *   category = @Translation("General"),
 *   default_widget = "url_textfield",
 *   default_formatter = "url"
 * )
 */
class UrlItem extends FieldItemBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition): array {
    return [
      'columns' => [
        'value' => [
          'type' => $field_definition->getSetting('is_ascii') === TRUE ? 'varchar_ascii' : 'varchar',
          'length' => (int) $field_definition->getSetting('max_length'),
          'binary' => $field_definition->getSetting('case_sensitive'),
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isEmpty(): bool {
    $value = $this->getValue();
    return empty($value['value']);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition): array {

    return [];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fieldSettingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {

    $settings = $this->getSettings();

    $element['allowed_schemes'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => $this->t('Allowed Schemes'),
      '#options' => $this->getSchemes(),
      '#default_value' => $settings['allowed_schemes'] ?? ['http', 'https'],
      '#description' => $this->t('Allowed URL schemes for the URL. If none are selected, then all are allowed.'),
    ];

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * Provide an array of URL schemes to allow.
   */
  public static function getSchemes(): array {

    return [
      'http' => 'http://',
      'https' => 'https://',
      'ftp' => 'ftp://',
      'mailto' => 'mailto://',
      'sftp' => 'sftp://',
      'ssh' => 'ssh://',
      'tel' => 'tel://',
    ];
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Shortest way to answer is that my plugin was a mess.
Lesson (re)learned...try to find examples of each method in an exemplar that takes the mystery out of the method.

Sorry, I had pasted the plugin again, but as pointed out, nothing meaningful had changed in it. I believe the issue was that I did not have a schema for the settings.

I added the file *url_text.schema.yml* to src/Plugin/Field/FieldType

```
field.field_settings.url:
  type: mapping
  label: 'URL settings'
  mapping:
    allowed_schemes:
      type: string
      label: 'Allowed Schemes'
```

The values are now saved.

Comment: This answer does not explain anything in terms of the question.

Comment: Between the `propertyDefinitions()` implementation defined in the answer and the implementation of the same method shown in the question there are no differences, since they both return an empty array. In the answer, the method sets `$properties['value']`, but that is a local variable which will vanish once the method returns to the caller.

Comment: Subsequent to these comments and the downvote on my answer I edited the answer to correct it,